# Configure iOS ADAL Azure SDK Storyboards

Tags: ios, authentication, azure, adal

I'm using https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc - ADAL library for iOS to connect to Azure AD.

I've built the Library and followed their instructions and I'm getting the following error - 
"**ADALiOS: ERROR: 
Error raised: 18. Additional Information: 
Domain: ADAuthenticationErrorDomain 
ProtocolCode:(null) 
Details:The required resource bundle could not be loaded. Please read the ADALiOS readme on how to build your application with ADAL provided authentication UI resources.. 
ErrorCode: 18**"

Looking at the source files, it states Error Code 18 deals with storyboards. Which I find confusing because I go as far as build their own sample @ https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-iOS  and I'm getting the same error...

Thanks in advance,

Comment: So, I got rid of that error...apparently the storyboard that contains the webviewcontroller has to be named, "ADAL...", in the sample it was labeled  "IPAL...". I made that change and the error goes away.

However, now I'm getting a " *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ADAuthenticationWebViewController initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e0c1d0' "

Answer (score 0):

So, what I did was simply make a new project with a Single View and brought over the ADAL_ storyboards and Headers and imported the ADAL library and it seems to work. I'm still kind of confused why their sample didn't build correctly but I'm going to consider this to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback Karl. The issue is that the sample cannot come bundled with the iOS SDK as both live independently, so you have to import the Storyboards.

However, we are working on an update that no longer requires storyboards.

I answered the question in more detail here: [Problems with resource bundles in adding Azure ADAL library to an iOS native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854520/problems-with-resource-bundles-in-adding-azure-adal-library-to-an-ios-native-app/25854622#25854622)

Comment: While building the ADALiOS for static library Do we select iOS Device or iOS simulator?

Comment: You should select iOS Device.

Comment: Is ADALiOS library Universal? as when I build it in iOS Device I am getting "Undefined symbols for architecture i386" issues.