# Problems with resource bundles in adding Azure ADAL library to an iOS native app

Tags: ios, xcode, azure, adal

I'm trying to follow the instructions for building a sample Native App client for iOS using Azure ADAL library and Azure AD sample app. The relevant components are:

https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-iOS

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc/releases/tag/1.0.1

I'm new to XCode and instructions for adding the ADAL library to the sample app are not clear for me. But I have followed the steps and added the library and linked the libADALiOS.a. As reported in another thread on this site, I get the following runtime error:

**2014-09-15 10:12:36.236 Microsoft Tasks[23140:60b] ADALiOS: ERROR: Error raised: 18. Additional Information: Domain: ADAuthenticationErrorDomain ProtocolCode:(null) Details:The required resource bundle could not be loaded. Please read the ADALiOS readme on how to build your application with ADAL provided authentication UI resources.. ErrorCode: 18.**

I have reviewed the ADAL README file carefully. Regarding the resource bundle in above error, it just  states:

```
"Add the storyboards from the ADALiOSBundle to your project resources"
```

Could someone familiar with ADAL (and xcode) simply enumerate the steps required for making the ADAL resource bundle loadable in a plain language for a newbie to understand? Do I need to move files, add some definitions to xcode, etc (note: my ADAL and app are both in the same workspace and should be visible)? The workaround mentioned in a separate threat on this problem was not clear to me either (changing resource names, rebuilding the bundle, etc that seems unnecessary if these sample apps are already functional).

Thanks, Ray

Answer (score 1):

Brandon from the ADAL team and the author of the sample.

I will make the instructions more clear.

Simply put - you need to drag the ADAL_iPhone_Storyboard.storyboard and ADAL_iPad_Storyboard.storyboard files in to your project under Supporting Files.

You can find the files under ADALiOSBundle:

[image]

Drag them to the sample folder "Supporting Files" as shown here:

[image: Shapshot of Support Files]

Comment: Brandon, thanks for your response. With your input and some digging, I got the issue resolved. Now I have some connectivity issues, but I suspect that's due to mismatch of some attributes between my client and the registered apps in AD. I'll work on  that separately. But please note that the client sources at the URL I mentioned above does not match your response. I needed to change the name of the bundles from IPAL_ to ADAL_ (as mentioned in an earlier post). It appears that there are multiple copies of the samples around.